# How to connect to main Flask APP from a remote server

Tags: python, linux, flask, ssh

```
 import psutil

STATS_URL = ' http://172.20.10.2:8080/report'
SERVER_NAME="test_local_server"

def get_health(): 

    print('generating health report')

    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2.0)
    ctime = psutil.cpu_times()
    disk_usage = psutil.disk_usage("/")
    net_io_counters = psutil.net_io_counters()
    virtual_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()    

    # The keys in this dict should match the db cols
    report = dict (
        USER_NAME="USER",
        SERVER_NAME="Test_Server",
        cpupercent = cpu_percent,
        cpu_total = ctime.user + ctime.system,
        free_Percnt=((disk_usage.free/disk_usage.used)*100),
        bytes_sent = net_io_counters.bytes_sent,
        bytes_received = net_io_counters.bytes_recv,
        packets_sent = net_io_counters.packets_sent,
        packets_received = net_io_counters.packets_recv,
        memory_Free = virtual_memory.free,
        )

    return report

if __name__=='__main__':


    print(f'starting health report stream for server :\t{SERVER_NAME}')

    while True:
        report = get_health()
        r = requests.post(STATS_URL, json=report)
        time.sleep(20)
```

I need to send the values of this script which is on an AWS remote server back to my Flask APP which is my main server on my windows laptop.

```
@app.route("/report",methods=['POST'])
def report():
    if request.method=='POST':
        time_epoch=time.time()
        incoming_report = request.get_json()
        print("Generating Health report")
        username=incoming_report["USER_NAME"]
        server_name=incoming_report["SERVER_NAME"]
        disk_free=incoming_report["free_Percnt"]
        bytes_sent=incoming_report["bytes_sent"]
        bytes_received=incoming_report["bytes_received"]
        packets_sent=incoming_report["packets_sent"]
        packets_received=incoming_report["packets_received"]
        memory_free=incoming_report["memory_Free"]
        cpu_percent=incoming_report["cpupercent"]
        cpu_total=incoming_report["cpu_total"]
        conn=sqlite3.connect("Health.db")
        conn.execute(f"create table if not exists {username}_{server_name} 
 (HEALTH_ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,Time_Epoch integer,Disk_Free varchar(80),Bytes_Sent varchar(80),Bytes_Received varchar(80),Packets_Sent varchar(80),Packets_Received varchar(80),Memory_Free varchar(80),Cpu_Usage_Percent varchar(80),Cpu_Time varchar(80));")
        conn.execute(f'insert into {username}_{server_name} (Time_Epoch,Disk_Free,Bytes_Sent,Bytes_Received,Packets_Sent,Packets_Received,Memory_Free,Cpu_Usage_Percent,Cpu_Time) values {time_epoch,disk_free,bytes_sent,bytes_received,packets_sent,packets_received,memory_free,cpu_percent,cpu_total}')
        conn.commit()
        return {'message': 'success'}



if __name__ ==("__main__"):
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

So i changed the host to '0.0.0.0' cause when i checked online thats what i found to make the flask app public but the connection from script says connection timed out.Can someone please help me send the values from the python script back to my flask app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward port `8080` on your router. Right now your home router is also a firewall and doesn't permit anything initiating a connection with a LAN machine (your PC). It needs to be told "if anyone tries to connect to our home IP at port 8080, connect it to my PC at the internal IP x.x.x.x"

Comment: how do you check what all ports are open?

Comment: @MathewPius The best option is to start with your home router web UI. You can, also, search online for a "check open ports" web service. Lastly, to test something closer to your specific app, you can install `nc` (netcat - an excellent networking tool) on your `AWS` machine attempt to open a connection on port 8080 with your home machine `nc -v <IP> 8080`. This quickly tests connectivity between your AWS machine and home one. You also have `nmap` for actual scanning but that's overkill (https://nmap.org/book/port-scanning-tutorial.html).